# SOLR 9.4 Cant access from outside server

Tags: solr

I have SOLR 9.4 installed and running on port 8983 on a windows server. I'm running JDK 21. On the server I can point a browser to http://localhost:8983/solr/# and the web interface comes up, and I am able to search a core successfully

Port 8983 is open, I can successfully tsc it over the port from Powershell from my local machine.

But when I open a browser from my local machine and point it to the server http://servername:8983/solr/# the browser says that it cant reach the page.

If I go back to the server, and bring up SOLR 8.11.1 on port 8983, I can successfully hit the site from my local machine.

Here are the parameters I am passing to SOLR 9.4 when running:

```
-DSTOP.KEY=stopsolr
-DSTOP.PORT=8087
-Djetty.home=E:\ApacheSolr9_4\server
-Djetty.logs=E:\ApacheSolr9_4\server\logs
-Djetty.port=8983
-Dorg.eclipse.jetty.util.log.SOURCE=true
-Dsolr.disable.shardsWhitelist=true
-Dsolr.enableRemoteStreaming=true
-Dsolr.enableStreamBody=true
-Dsolr.log.dir=E:\ApacheSolr9_4\server\logs
-Dsolr.solr.home=E:\ApacheSolr9_4\server\solr
-Dsolr.solr.home=solr
```